# Makefile results in multiple definition errors

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
TARGET = main.elf
BUILD_DIR = build
SRC_DIR = src

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc -std=gnu17
CXX = arm-none-eabi-g++ -std=c++17 
LINKER = arm-none-eabi-g++
OBJDUMP = arm-none-eabi-objdump
OBJCOPY = arm-none-eabi-objcopy

INCLUDES = -I./src/inc \
           -I./src/usys/inc

SRC_FILES_C =   $(SRC_DIR)/usys/startup.c \
                $(SRC_DIR)/usys/usys.c

SRC_FILES_CXX = $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp

LINKER_FILE = $(SRC_DIR)/usys/flash.ld

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g3 -O0
CFLAGS += -c -mthumb -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -DARM
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m33 -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard --specs=nano.specs

LFLAGS = -mcpu=cortex-m33 --specs=nosys.specs --specs=nano.specs
LFLAGS += -T$(LINKER_FILE) -Wl,-Map="$(TARGET).map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static
LFLAGS += -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -Wl,--end-group

C_OBJS = ${subst $(SRC_DIR),$(BUILD_DIR),$(SRC_FILES_C:.c=.o)}
CXX_OBJS = ${subst $(SRC_DIR),$(BUILD_DIR),$(SRC_FILES_CXX:.cpp=.o)}

ALL_OBJS = $(CXX_OBJS) $(C_OBJS)

.PHONY: clean

all: $(TARGET)

# Compile
$(C_OBJS): $(SRC_FILES_C)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(CXX_OBJS): $(SRC_FILES_CXX)
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Link
$(TARGET): $(ALL_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJS) -o $@

# Clean
clean:
    @rm -f $(ALL_OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

My source directly roughly looks like this:

```
├───build
│   └───usys
├───src
|   main.cpp
│   └───usys
|       startup.c
|       usys.c
│       └───inc
└───tools
```

When I compile my program, I get multiple definition errors when linking.  Which makes sense, because during compilation, I see the following:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -std=gnu17 -I./src/inc -I./src/usys/inc -Wall
> -Wextra -g3 -O0 -c -mthumb -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -DARM -mcpu=cortex-m33 -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard --specs=nano.specs -c **src/usys/startup.c -o build/usys/usys.o**

How can I modify my Makefile so that it does what I want: take the list of `$(SRC_FILES_C)`, and creates the objects in the output at `$(C_OBJS)`?

Comment: All your C_OBJS depend on all your SRC_FILES_C?

Comment: main.o depends on main.c, startup.o depends on startup.c, usys.o depends on usys.c.  Is that line not doing what I think it's doing?

Comment: Yes, as DevSolar said it makes every .o depend on every .c.

Comment: Normally you'd use wildcard rules: `%.c.o : %.c`, and so on.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've tried that solution, but because my .c/.cpp files are nested in folders, it doesn't work out-of-the-box.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to be more specific, making it more useful to future visitors. Feel free to improve it further.

Comment: Nesting doesn't matter, you can just do `obj/%.c.o : src/%.c`. `%` itself doesn't do any file search by itself, it only kicks in for files listed as prerequisites in `$(TARGET): $(ALL_OBJS)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
$(C_OBJS): $(SRC_FILES_C)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

`$(SRC_FILES_C)` expands to a list of *all* the source files, and `$<` subsequently takes the first of these, which is `src/usys/startup.c`. This file is used as the input for *each* object file.

Instead, you're looking for a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html). A pattern rule is only applied if all prerequisites already exist or can be made (`make`d). Thanks to this, you can use pattern rules for both `.c` and `.cpp` files:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Sure, but for this to work, I'll need to add a VPATH and get rid of my list list of files: `SRC_FILES_C` and `SRC_FILES_CXX`?  I'd rather have a specified list than a VPATH, but if that's the only way to do it...

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the part where you are doing an out-of-tree build. Edited.

Comment: Thank you.  I remember thinking this wouldn't be the solution because for instance, the first line in your second code block reads to me as "Take all the c files in the src/ directory, and make their corresponding object files".  But how would it know about the src/**usys** files?

Comment: It's wrong to think about pattern rules that way.  Patterns are not globbing.  They don't say "go look for everything that matches this and do something with it".  A pattern rule is a template.  It means, "if you're trying to build a target X, and it matches the target pattern, and you can build the prerequisites, then use this recipe to build X".

Comment: Also, it's not right to think about "here's a bunch of source, what can I build with it?".  make works in exactly the opposite way; it starts from the _target_ and works _backwards_.  So it says, "oh you want to build target FOO; OK how do I build that.... I can built it from these prerequisites, so how do I build those?" and so on recursively.  If it uses all your source files fine; if not, that's fine (with make) as well.

Comment: @MadScientist That's really good stuff.  I've never grokked Makefiles my entire career.  Partially because they're not sexy, and it's only a small portion of time I spend on them, but it's probably partially because I don't think about them in the right way as well.  That advice does help.